# Renault Megane not starting after water damage

Tags: electrical, starting, diesel, renault, water

Im looking at a Renault Megane 2010 1.5 dci which was crashed into a drain. ECU and electrics on left hand side were submerged. Have changed ECU, circuit box on top of left suspension, circuit box by glove box, card reader and electrical box on steering column.

Have ignition and turns over four or five times but won't start. Does anyone know if there is any other electrical component that needs to be fitted or is there something else that could be causing this?

Comment: Does the ecu need to be coded to the vehicle - ie the security / alarm system?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!